# recursive tree parsing with vba

Tags: vba, excel

Given the following spreadsheet of data: https://ethercalc.org/q7n9zwbzym5y

I have the following code that will parse this and will derive a tree from the parent-child relationships in the sheet. Note that fact that every column occurs twice is because the first instance of the columns is for another type of data, I am only concerned with the populated columns. This is the desired output from the sheet above:
[image]

Code:

```
Sub performanceSheet(someParams)
' Write to "Performance" sheet
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet, wsSearch As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
    Dim num_rows
    Dim parent As Range, parentName As String
    Dim parentRange As Range, childrenRange As Range
    Dim childCount As Long
    Dim p As Variant
    Dim f1 As Range, f2 As Range
    currRow = 8


    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set w1 = wbk.Sheets("PositionsDB")
    Set w2 = wbk.Sheets("Performance")

    num_rows = w1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    'If there's no parentName column, we can't continue.
    If w1.Rows(1).Find("portfolioName") Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'find first instance
    Set f1 = w1.Rows(1).Find("portfolioName", lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f1 Is Nothing Then
        'find second instance
        Set f2 = f1.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, w1.Columns.Count - f1.Column).Find("portfolioName", lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f2 Is Nothing Then
            'set range based on f2
            Set parentRange = w1.Range(f2.Offset(1, 0), _
                                       w1.Cells(Rows.Count, f2.Column).End(xlUp))

        End If
    End If
    'If there's no Root level, how do we know where to start?
    If parentRange.Find("Main") Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each parent In parentRange
        If Not dict.Exists(parent.Value) Then
            childCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(parentRange, parent.Value)
            Set childrenRange = parent.Offset(, 2).Resize(childCount, 1)
            dict.Add parent.Value, Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(childrenRange.Value))
        End If
    Next
    ' Recursive method to traverse our dictionary, beginning at Root element.
    Call PerformanceProcessItem("", "Main", dict, w2, 9)

    wbk.Sheets("Performance").Columns("A:F").AutoFit

End Sub


Private Sub PerformanceProcessItem(parentName As String, name As String, dict As Object, ws As Worksheet, row_num As Long, Optional indent As Long = 0)
    Dim output As String, v
    Dim w2 As Worksheet


    'Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", indent) & name
    'Debug.Print parentName & name

    'write to sheet
    ws.Cells(row_num, 3).Value = name

    row_num = row_num + 1
    If Not dict.Exists(name) Then
        'we're at a terminal element, a child with no children.
        Exit Sub
    Else
            For Each v In dict(name)
                ' ## RECURSION ##
                Call PerformanceProcessItem(name, CStr(v), dict, ws, row_num, indent + 2)
            Next
    End If

End Sub
```

However, when creating this tree, it gets stuck on an infinite loop of India's, where after recognizing "Cash" as the terminal element of India, rather than exiting that subtree it will create another India and continue until overflow. Is there a logic error in my code? Hours of debugging hasn't worked for me and any input would be appreciated on where I have a flaw in my logic.

Comment: There's no data in your online spreadsheet?

Comment: There is @TimWilliams :) You will have to scroll up

Comment: @SiddharthRout How so? Going forwards, I wanted to assign a priority-structure too, for instance having Cash always be at the bottom of every subtree, meaning that an iterative solution wouldn't be expandable into that.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I only see headers

Comment: @TimWilliams: I see https://prnt.sc/l0xdpa

Comment: @TimWilliams you need to scroll right, there is some empty columns initially.

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes, considering I resolve columns by header name and not index it should be a very simple transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that "Main" and "Cash" will always be there. If not then we will have to tweak the code little bit. I have commented the code so you may not have a problem understanding it. But if you do, simply ask. I quickly wrote this code so I am sure it can be optimized :)

```
Option Explicit

Dim sB As String
Dim tmpAr As Variant

Sub Sample()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim s As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim itm As Variant, vTemp As Variant

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet

    With ws
        '~~> Get Last Row of Col AA
        lRow = .Range("AA" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '~~> Store Range AA:AC in an array
        tmpAr = .Range("AA2:AC" & lRow).Value
    End With

    '~~> Create a unique collection of portfolioName
    For i = LBound(tmpAr) To UBound(tmpAr)
        If tmpAr(i, 1) = "Main" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add tmpAr(i, 3), CStr(tmpAr(i, 3))
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next i

    '~~> Sort the collection
    For i = 1 To col.Count - 1
         For j = i + 1 To col.Count
             If col(i) > col(j) Then
                vTemp = col(j)
                col.Remove j
                col.Add vTemp, vTemp, i
             End If
         Next j
    Next i

    s = "Main"

    For Each itm In col
        sB = vbTab & itm
        s = s & vbNewLine & sB
        sB = ""
        GetParentChild itm, 2
        If Trim(sB) <> "" Then _
        s = s & vbNewLine & sB
    Next itm
    s = s & vbNewLine & vbTab & "Cash"
    Debug.Print s
End Sub

Private Sub GetParentChild(strg As Variant, n As Integer)
    Dim sTabs As String
    Dim j As Long, k As Long

    For k = 1 To n
        sTabs = sTabs & vbTab
    Next k

    For j = LBound(tmpAr) To UBound(tmpAr)
        If Trim(tmpAr(j, 1)) = Trim(strg) And Trim(tmpAr(j, 1)) <> "Cash" Then
            sB = sB & sTabs & tmpAr(j, 3) & vbNewLine

            GetParentChild tmpAr(j, 3), n + 1
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

This is what I got when I ran it on the data that you provided.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I should have specified. I need to have my tree delimited by indents rather than different cells for output purposes. Is it possible to convert this code to handle that?

Comment: The data is in the array. You can loop through the array and indent it :)

Comment: I'm trying to dissect this, and from my understanding this doesn't handle the depth of the tree I'm looking to create? I'm not sure how to use the collection of parent names and tempArrays how to handle a size "n" depth.

Comment: If what you see in Excel Image above is what you want (minus indentation) then the depth of the tree is not a problem. :) All you have to do is loop through the array and create indents using `vbTab`

Comment: Ah, well the Excel image is different from the output my recursive algorithm gives me. In the Excel image, the parents are all outermost parents even if they are a child of another parent. I think you would still need an algorithm to turn this code into a full tree

Comment: I was referring to my excel image :)

Comment: Yes, so was I. Your iterative approach doesn't create a tree, only a list of parents and children. You would still need to use this in conjunction with some other code which makes the solution more difficult, and doesn't address my issue at hand. I like how this code can handle some basic priority but I believe it is much less flexible than my recursive approach...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181104/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-evariste-galois).