# vba - building a dictionary of parent child key value pairs

Tags: vba, excel

Given the following columns of data:

```
portfolioID portfolioName   entityID    entityName
-188    India   643365  someLeaf1
-188    India   642925  someLeaf2
-188    India   643008  someLeaf3
-188    India   66280   Cash
-187    Main    -186    Golf
-187    Main    -181    Charlie
-187    Main    66280   Cash
-187    Main    66281   Alpha
-187    Main    66283   Bravo
-186    Golf    -185    Hotel
-186    Golf    -183    Juliet
-186    Golf    66280   Cash
-185    Hotel   -188    India
-185    Hotel   397660  Xray
-185    Hotel   66280   Cash
-183    Juliet  -182    Kilo
-183    Juliet  66280   Cash
-183    Juliet  66281   Lima
-182    Kilo    596371  someLeaf4
-182    Kilo    66280   Cash
-182    Kilo    602616  someLeaf5
-182    Kilo    602617  someLeaf6
-181    Charlie -180    Delta
-181    Charlie -179    Echo
-181    Charlie 66280   Cash
-180    Delta   641311  someLeaf7
-180    Delta   641312  someLeaf8
-180    Delta   641313  someLeaf9
-180    Delta   641314  someLeaf10
-180    Delta   66280   Cash
-179    Echo    66280   Cash
-179    Echo    66281   Foxtrot
```

You can derive a tree from the relationships above, where portfolioName's are parents and entityName's are children:

[image: tree]

I want to iterate over this and build a scripting dictionary of parents with childRanges. This is my current code:

```
For Each parent In parentRange
    If Not dict.Exists(parent.Value) Then
        childCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(parentRange, parent.Value)
        Set childrenRange = parent.Offset(, 2).Resize(childCount, 1)
        dict.Add parent.Value, Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(childrenRange.Value))
    End If
Next
```

However, this does not work when the data is not sorted by parents. How can I change my childrenRange to the proper list of children most efficiently?

Also, is it possible to always have "Cash" be the final element of the array of children?

Attempt:

```
for Each parent In parentRange
        If Not dict.Exists(parent.Value) Then
            childCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(parentRange, parent.Value)
            'Set childrenRange = parent.Offset(, 2).Resize(childCount, 1)
            Dim childrenArr() As String
            ReDim childrenArr(childCount)
            Dim c As Integer
            c = 0
            For i = 1 To num_rows
                If Cells(i, f2.Column).Value = parent Then
                    childrenArr(c) = Cells(i, f2.Column).Offset(2, 0)
                    c = c + 1
                End If
            Next i
            dict.Add parent.Value, childrenArr
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595224/recursive-tree-parsing-with-vba

Comment: Seems like if the data isn't sorted then you'd need to loop over the rows and add the children (and parent as needed) one-by one. You can still use `countif` to size the original array in each case (to avoid the need for Redim Preserve)  Did you try something like that?  If you want "Cash" to be last in each array then you can either place it in that location when you're filling the arrays, or you can move it there when done with the filling.

Comment: Read all into an array and do something hideous with dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries etc....

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated my post with an attempt at what you're suggesting but I don't think I implemented it correctly... am I missing something?

Comment: As a followup, is it possible to convert an array to a Range type? My followup subroutine has a dependency on iterating over `Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(childrenRange.Value))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim parentRange As Range, p As Range, c
    Dim m, childrenArr() As String, tmp
    Dim dict, childCount As Long, k
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set parentRange = Range("B2:B33")

    For Each p In parentRange
        'create an empty array if a new key
        If Not dict.Exists(p.Value) Then
            childCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(parentRange, p.Value)
            ReDim childrenArr(0 To childCount - 1)
            dict.Add p.Value, childrenArr
        End If

        tmp = dict(p.Value) '<<get the array
        c = p.Offset(0, 2).Value
        If c = "Cash" Then
            tmp(UBound(tmp)) = c
        Else
            'find first empty slot (will be 1-based)
            m = Application.Match("", tmp, 0)
            tmp(m - 1) = c 'minus one because array is 0-based
        End If
        dict(p.Value) = tmp '<<return the array
    Next

    For Each k In dict.keys
        Debug.Print k, Join(dict(k), ", ")
    Next k

End Sub
```

Note: if you want to work with an array contained in a dictionary you first need to pull it out of the dictionary.